# Editing hash-data from database by using Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, activeadmin

How to edit a hash from database? By default the hash will be escaped – so it isn't a valid hash by reading it again.

For example I got a Table named „Data“ with the column „hash_data“.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Data do

  permit_params :hash_data

  form do |f|
    f.input :hash_data
    f.input :hidden
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is easy. We need an eval(). So we are able to save a „real“ hash to the database. So instead using the „hash_data=“ method we have to create a ne method named „hash_data_raw=“.

The new model:

```
class Data < ActiveRecord::Base

  def hash_data_raw
    self.hash_data
  end

  def hash_data_raw=(values)
    self.hash_data=eval(values)
  end

end
```

Now we have to use the „hash_data_raw“ methodes at Active Admin.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Data do
  permit_params :hash_data

  form do |f|
    f.input :hash_data_raw, :as => :text
    f.actions
  end

end
```

Comment: what's the point of asking a question and answer it instantly?

Comment: i want to share the results of a long search http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: eval is a really bad way to go about this - I'd use json or yaml or something. A typo could crash your server.

Comment: right a eval() is bad! but how to do it else? In that case I want do to be able to save a ruby on rails hash. There is no hash() or something that builds a new hashes out of old ones with unknown depth. Or I am wrong?